# Best way to show info notification and requests with Yes/no button.

Tags: web-app, dashboard

What would be a good practice to show only info notifications and request notifications for accepting/declining CTA buttons?

Is it good to merge them and show it in one notifications tab or keep them separated?

The info notifications contain general info messages and the request notifications contain notifications of getting friends requests and other requests that need the user to do some actions on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these kind of situations I always look at what other big players do. In your case there are some huge players.

For example Facebook. Facebook is so huge and widely used, any interaction patterns they have might be considered convention. If you would implement something similar, people would already be familiar with it. Facebook separates friend requests and notifications.

[image]

LinkedIn uses the same pattern.

[image]

**Conclusion**
Going with conventions, the answer to your question would be to keep it separated. That is, friend/connection requests from other notifications.
If we look into why Facebook and Linkedin keep these two types of notifications separated is because their entire concept thrives on you having many friends and connections. Friend requests might get lost in the sea of notifications you might get on a daily basis.
You might want to take a look at your concept the same way. Is it important that they interact with these CTA notifications? If yes, keep them separated, so you'll be sure your users won't miss any CTA notifications.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What i noticed in linkedin that they use the flag icon. Which can be used for showing requests and bell icon for showing the general info messages.